# Test machine (Win7 laptop) redirect server UNC paths back to same test machine

Tags: windows-7, hosts, netbios, unc, fqdn

I have a Windows7 laptop for developing at home.

The live application makes calls to the SQL Database ("CANCENTRESRV") which I have been succesful in redirecting back to the my laptop using HOSTS entries for CANCENTRESRV to point to 127.0.0.1 etc. and loading recent copies of the database for testing purposes onto a SqlExpress version of SQLSERVER.

The application then manipulates (e.g opens, prints, emails) documents based on a UNC path from the server IndexedDocumentTables.PathName that points to there real-life location on then real Document Server

e.g ("\SADOCCANCENTRE.REALDOMAIN.COM\CANDATA\Letters\letterA.doc").

I have added SADOCCANCENTRE to lmhosts and hosts to point back to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) and added using Registry editor "OptionNames" of "SADOCCANCENTRE" for Netbios name resolution to \HKLM...\LanMan\Parameters...

Now I can PING SADOCCANCENTRE and SADOCANCENTRE.REALDOMAIN.COM and get 127.0.0.1 (ie back to the test bed), and \SADOCCANCENTRE\ shows the shares on my test machine.. but \SANDOCCACENTRE.REALDOMAIN.COM\ fails.

How do i do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be encountering the LoopbackCheck security functionality; there is a registry setting that can be used to disable the functionality for non-production systems.

**Error message when you try to access a server locally by using its FQDN or its CNAME alias**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926642

Comment: This seems to have worked.. now answering on both \\fqdns and \\netbios name.. I ended up adding this support kb recommendation, plus also the related support kb.